# Bootstrap collapsed menu height issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap menu that looks like this when opened in mobile mode:

[image]

If you notice, there's a dropdown menu item in the navbar titled "RESOURCES". This menu has the following sub-items:

> ACTION
>
> ANOTHER ACTION
>
> SOMETHING ELSE HERE
>
> SEPARATED LINK
>
> ONE MORE SEPARATED LINK

However, when the menu is opened in mobile mode, it only shows a part of the list with a scrollbar that one can move up and down to view the rest of the list (the scrollbar is only visible during scroll hence can't be seen in the screenshot below):

[image]

If I change the overlay property of the `.navbar-collapse` class to `visible` (`.navbar-collapse.in { overflow: visible; }`), it does show the full menu without the need to scroll but then it seems to overflow the navbar itself making it illegible:

[image]

Is there any way to make sure the navbar height increases with the content when menu items are expanded without having to manually intervene? If manual intervention is the only option I have, how do I go about doing it dynamically? The height cannot have a static value as it would depend on the device, right?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="HeaderController">
      <!-- Search box start -->
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right search-box" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" OnMouseOver="$(this).focus();">
          <span class="fa fa-search search-icon"></span>
          <!--<div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>-->
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- Search box end -->
      <!-- Nav menu links start -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
          <li><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#">PREMIUM</a></li>
          <li class="menuhead dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">RESOURCES<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">ACTION</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">ANOTHER ACTION</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SOMETHING ELSE HERE</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">SEPARATED LINK</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">ONE MORE SEPARATED LINK</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="centerAlignModal()" data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- nav menu links end -->
    </div>
```

I tried adding the CSS attributes `height: auto;` and `clear: both;` to the `navbar-collapse` div but it didn't do anything.

**UPDATE:** Here's what I tried in JQuery but didn't get the desired result (the relevant bit is in the `else{}` block):

```
$('.navbar-fixed-top').click('li', function(e) {
    var head = e.target.parentElement.className;
    if (head.indexOf("menuhead") < 0){ $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide'); }
    else {
        var navbar = $('.top-nav');
        var dropdown = e.target.parentElement;
        var navbottom = navbar.offset().top + navbar.outerHeight();
        var dropdownbottom = dropdown.offset().top + dropdown.outerHeight();
        if(dropdownbottom < navbottom){
            $('.top-nav').css('height', navbar[0].scrollHeight + dropdown.scrollHeight + 'px');
        }
        else {
            $('.top-nav').css('height', navbar[0].scrollHeight - dropdown.scrollHeight + 'px');
        }
    }
});
```

There seem to be two issues with my JS: 1) It throws an error saying `offset()` is not a function for `var dropdown`?, and 2) It doesn't add the total height of the expanded `<li>` to the `navbar` div, although it does add a few pixels!

Comment: You need to post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: For 1) isn't `offset()` a jQuery method so not available on `dropdown` because `e.target.parentElement` return a native DOM element. `$(e.target.parentElement)` would give it the jQuery methods.

Comment: In that case, do you have any idea on how to retrieve the "bottom" value of the clicked `<li>`? If I use `$(e.target.parentElement)`, it returns an array of classes but that leaves me with no option to reference this one `li` specifically and retrieve its `bottom` value for further comparisons.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be the way I am doing. All I need is to ensure that the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"` expands when a dropdown item within it (one of the `<li class="menuhead dropdown">` items) is clicked. Currently, the expanded dropdown is being pushed outside the navbar in mobile mode.